# @SessionAttributes how to clear properly a session attribute

Tags: forms, session, spring-mvc, controller

I would like to create a normal form wizard with a special action on confirm page.

1. Acquire form data (form is pre-filled with a session attributes)
2. On press OK, save form data by posting JSON and update
   sessions attributes
3. show form on summary page with updated sessions attributes
4. On press OK, save form data to my storage. On press "Correct", I go back to Step 1 (form is pre-filled with updated session attributes).
5. Show confirm page (with a successful message) and show a
   "Print" button (which is another page) and remove session attributes by calling `SessionStatus#setComplete()`

My problem is when the user want to print on confirm page (he go to the print page), but my session attribute has been destroyed on step 5. And I am loosing my model data.
If I remove `SessionStatus#setComplete()`, when a user come back to step 1, previous data are pre-filled instead of new data.

So, how can I do this ?

```
 @SessionAttributes({"addressForm", "userContactDetails", "newAddressInformation"})
    public class AddressProfileController {
    //....

    @ModelAttribute("addressForm")
    public AddressForm getAddressForm() {
            // Form is pre-filled
        return webModelMapper.processMapping(new AddressForm(), getUserContactDetails().getAddressInformation());
    }

    @ModelAttribute("newAddressInformation")
    public AddressInformation getNewAddressInformation() {
        return new AddressInformation();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userContactDetails")
    public ContactDetails getUserContactDetails() {
        return profilService.getUserContactDetails();
    }
    //....
```

On step 2, I am updating `newAddressInformation` with new `addressForm` values
So if I go back to Step 1, new values are pre-filled on form.

Step 5, remove session attributes on confirm page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dcr/dcr-confirmation-adresse.html")
    public String confirmUserAddressForm(@ModelAttribute("newAddressInformation") AddressInformation newAddressInformation, @ModelAttribute("userContactDetails") ContactDetails contactDetails, Model model, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        // do something
        sessionStatus.setComplete(); // invalidate session attributes
```

After step 5, session attribute is not available (with previous data):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/print-address.html")
    public String printUserAddressForm(@ModelAttribute("newAddressInformation") AddressInformation newAddressInformation, @ModelAttribute("userContactDetails") ContactDetails contactDetails, Model model) {   
            // newAddressInformation is empty bean, because session attributes has been previously detroyed
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dcr/dcr-confirmation-adresse.html")
    public String confirmUserAddressForm(@ModelAttribute("newAddressInformation") AddressInformation newAddressInformation, @ModelAttribute("userContactDetails") ContactDetails contactDetails, Model model, SessionStatus sessionStatus, HttpServletRequest request) {
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("addressForm", addressForm);
```

so you set the session attribute with your updated object!

Comment: If I delete `sessionStatus.setComplete`, I got problem on my step 1 (new values are pre-filled on form)

Comment: 1) You have addressForm object:
- Street = A, City = B
You can change the values - Street = C
2) When you press OK u get a newAddressInformation object in the controller with values Street = C, City = B. Now you update the addressForm object from Streez = A to Street = C and show the summary page! 
3) When you press OK on the summary page, you would like to persist the new data, when u press Correct you return to the frist page with values Street = C, City = B!

Is this correct? Can u tell me on which page you use which object? And can you post your changes from my previous answer?

Comment: Because address can be update by another way (for example mobile apps). If user start changing is address and confirm in webapp. After he correct his address on mobile device. And he would like to adjust something on the webapp. Webapp can not contains new data set on device, because webapp use data in session... Is it possible to remove only some session attributes (in my case "addressForm"), not all ?

Comment: There is no way to reuse session attribute after setComplete or remove a specific session attribute ? (instead of using HttpSession)

Comment: Maybe it exists, I don't know another way.. but have you tried it with HttpSession? is it working?